# Is it possible to style an html element, so that it won't 'hurt' inner styles

Tags: html, css

I'm building some sort of framework where the content of the page can be edited with [ContentTools](http://getcontenttools.com). A requirement of ContentTools is that the [regions must be parents](http://getcontenttools.com/getting-started#regions-must-be-parents).

If you try this:

```
<h1 data-editable data-name="heading">Content</h1>
```

It wont work as a region has to contain editable block level elements. A way around this is to wrap the tag like so:

```
<div data-editable data-name="heading">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

But I just want to make the text editable, so I automatically wrapped the inner elements in a div. This works but it affects the styles.

Is there a way to make a div 'transparent', so it will inherit all styles? 
I tried the following code.

*To be clear: In this example I don't write the h1 css, so i have no influence over which styles are used.*

```js
$("[data-editable]").wrapInner("<div class='innerWrap'></div>");
```

```css
/* example h1 css, could be anything */
body > h1{
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid green;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

.innerWrap{
  all: inherit;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 data-editable data-name="heading">Content</h1>
```

As you can see some things work. But things like a border will double.
It has to be no difference with or without the innerWrap.

Is it possible to do this with css? It has to work on every css property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap the h1 with a div not div with h1.
for eg. `.wrapInner()` will produce something like

```
<h1 data-editable="" data-name="heading">
  <div class="innerWrap">Content</div>
</h1>
```

But what you want is

```
<div data-editable data-name="heading">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

So please try with `.wrap()` instead of `.wrapInner()`

```js
$("[data-editable]").wrap("<div class='innerWrap'></div>");
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid green;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

.innerWrap{
  all: inherit;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 data-editable data-name="heading">Content</h1>
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of this. But it wont work because of some selectors like `body > #wrapper > h1`

Answer (score 0):

```
.innerWrap{
   all: inherit;  /* remove it*/
}
```

As a default behaviour, if you not specify css props for ".innerWrap" it will look same as parent only

Answer (score 0):

The ability to make an individual element editable standalone as opposed to as part of a collection (e.g in a region) is currently being worked on: https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/issues/79

There is however a short-term **imperfect** approach you could try, first change you're HTML as follows:

```
<h1 data-editable data-name="heading">
    <span data-inline data-ce-tag="h1">Content</span>
</h1>
```

This will make the `h1` tag the region and tell ContentTools/Edit to treat the inner `span` element as a `h1` (text) element (thanks to the `data-ce-tag`).

But the next problem is that if the user hit's return you'll end up with a new paragraph tag inside of your `h1` - which we don't want. This is where the `data-inline` attribute comes in, we need to listen for mount events and if the element mounted has the `data-inline` attribute we'll modify its behaviour so it can't do certain things which might produce undesirable events:

```
ContentEdit.Root.get().bind('mount', function(elem) {
    // We're only interested in elements that are marked as inline
    if (elem.attr('data-inline') === undefined) {
        return;
    }

    // Change the default behaviour of the element
    elem.can('drag', false);
    elem.can('drop', false);
    elem.can('remove', false);
    elem.can('spawn', false);
});
```

You can find out more about modifying behaviours [here](http://getcontenttools.com/api/content-edit#behaviours), along with their current limitations [here](https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/releases/tag/1.2.2).